# How do you trigger a Google Analytics event for section scroll using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-tag-manager

We have section in a page where the content inside the section in scrollable within that particular section. i.e the Height of the section is fixed but we can add any length of content inside that section and scroll bar is applied to that section so that user can scroll and see the content inside the section.

Now my required is tracking the event when some uses/scrolls the custom scroll applied for that section. Is there a way to trigger an event for this scenario?